# cron output options when using curl

Tags: php, cron

when running a cron job like this:

curl http://example.com/cronjob.php

The output email contains this:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

 0    52    0    52    0     0     81      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    81
 0    52    0    52    0     0     31      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
 0    98    0    98    0     0     37      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--    23
 0    98    0    98    0     0     27      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--    15
 0    98    0    98    0     0     21      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--    11
100   144    0   144    0     0     25      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--    18
100   144    0   144    0     0     21      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--    18
100   190    0   190    0     0     23      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--    17
100   190    0   190    0     0     21      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--    17
100   236    0   236    0     0     24      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--    27
```

I find this totally useless and would prefer just the code output. **Is there any way to disable this?**

I don't get this if the cronjob is run like below:

> php /path/to/the/phpfile.php

But right now, I do not have a choice but to use curl.

Comment: What does your PHP script do?

Comment: It makes a lot of API calls and stores the data to a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried invoking curl with --silent?

```
curl --silent http://example.com/cronjob.php
```

or

```
curl -s http://example.com/cronjob.php
```

from the [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

-s/--silent

Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl mute.